# Unable to invoke AWS Lambda Function URL from another Lambda function in the same account

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-iam

I have 2 python lambda functions in the same AWS account. Function 1 has the function url ability enabled, with AWS_IAM authentication enabled. Function 2 is designed to call function 1, using the urllib library. I have set up the following resource policy on Function 1

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Id": "default",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "my-custom-id001",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::xxxxxxxxxxxx:role/service-role/Function-2-role"
      },
      "Action": "lambda:InvokeFunctionUrl",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:lambda:ap-southeast-2:xxxxxxxxxxxx:function:Function-1",
      "Condition": {
        "StringEquals": {
          "lambda:FunctionUrlAuthType": "AWS_IAM"
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

I would expect this would allow Function 2 to invoke Function 1, but I get a 403 Forbidden when I try from the AWS Console (by using 'test' on Function 2). I know it's not the code at either end, as the invocation works fine when I change the authentication from AWS_IAM to NONE. Where am I going wrong? I've also tried instead to give Function 2 an explicit policy allowing it to invoke the function url of Function 1, with the same result:

Policy on Function 2

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "lambda:InvokeFunctionUrl",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:lambda:ap-southeast-2:xxxxxxxxxxxx:function:Function-1"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Show us the source code for how the lambda function is invoking the other one

Comment: How have you configured the Urllib library to use the IAM credentials exactly? Why not just call the Lambda Invoke API directly instead of trying to use the URL endpoint?

Comment: The scenario above is just a test to make sure everything works. In a production scenario, the Lambda Url will be invoked by 3rd party tools. Having a Lambda set up to call the URL is just a useful test rig. I wasn't aware you needed to configure Urllib to use the IAM credentials? The AWS documentation doesn't specify that need https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/urls-auth.html